# How do I build a Multiple Criteria Index in R, incorporating > and < operators?

Tags: r, data.table

I'm trying to lookup and merge two data frames I have on multiple criteria and having a lot of trouble making sense of it.

I've got two sets of data, one I'm looking to index against that contains the validity dates of some products and the other that gives me product use, as follows:

```
    Indexset <- data.table(validfrom=as.Date(c("2015-08-01", "2015-08-02", "2015-08-03", "2015-08-04")),
                         validto=as.Date(c("2015-08-07", "2015-08-08","2015-08-09", "2015-08-10")),
                         username=c("Smith", "Cole", "Amos", "Richardson"),
                         productcode=c(1,2,3,4))

    Useset <- data.table(usedate=as.Date(c("2015-08-04", "2015-08-06", "2015-08-06", "2015-08-09")),
                     username=c("Smith", "Richardson", "Cole", "Amos"))
```

What I'm looking to do is add a column to 'Useset' that will contain the 'productcode' from 'Indexset' by checking the 'usedate' is between the 'validto' & 'validfrom' dates and then matching the name.

I've tried various ways around the 'merge' function but couldn't work out how to get the greater than and less than operators into the syntax.

Have also tried setting and rolling joins but struggling to make them work.

Currently migrating from excel where this would just be a multiple criteria index match in an array but not sure how to put it together in R.

To be clear, I'm not hitting errors, just completely lost in putting the syntax together.

Once I have the 'productcodes' I think I can handle the merge but absolutely stumped here!

Would appreciate any help anyone can offer!

Comment: In the new version of `data.table`, you can do that or another option is `foverlaps`

Comment: If your index set covers all intervals of time an individual might appear in, then ... `Useset[, v := Indexset[Useset, on=c("username", validfrom = "usedate"), roll=TRUE]$productcode ]` should work even on 1.9.6, I think. It's an awkward way to use a rolling join, not sure if there's a better way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may try the `non-equi` join feature from the current development version of `data.table`, v1.9.7. Please read the installation instructions [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation).

```
Useset[Indexset, on = .(username, usedate >= validfrom, usedate <= validto), # which rows?
         productcode := productcode][]                                       # what to do?

#       usedate   username productcode
# 1: 2015-08-01      Smith           1
# 2: 2015-08-04 Richardson           4
# 3: 2015-08-02       Cole           2
# 4: 2015-08-03       Amos           3
```

`Usenet` gets updated *in-place*.

---

If the performance is not a big issue, join on `username` and then filter should also work, this does not require the dev version of `data.table`:

```
Useset[Indexset, on = "username"][usedate >= validfrom & usedate <= validto, .(usedate, username, productcode)]
#      usedate   username productcode
# 1: 2015-08-01      Smith           1
# 2: 2015-08-02       Cole           2
# 3: 2015-08-03       Amos           3
# 4: 2015-08-04 Richardson           4
```

Comment: Psidom, very nice answer! Made a few (minor) edits (with explanation in the edit history). Feel free to rollback.

Comment: In your second solution, it might be better to make it clear that you mean "memory" by performance (since the number of matching rows by "username" alone could explode).

Comment: @Arun thanks. I think those are good edits, making it more convenient for people to find the resources.

Comment: Thanks very much for this gents, that was a major headache. Second solution does what I need but I'll have a play with the first one too. @Arun - Enjoying your DataCamp course!

Comment: Glad you are liking the Datacamp course. Thanks for supporting.